# cannot apply middleware to apollo server

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, apollo-server

im trying this approach

```
import express, { Application } from 'express';
import { ApolloServer } from 'apollo-server-express';
import { buildSchema } from 'type-graphql';
    async function startServer() {
    const app: Application = express(); //trying to cast  it into Applicaton  because  of another error
    await connectDatabase();
    
    
        const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
          schema: await buildSchema({
            resolvers: [UserResolver],
            authChecker,
          }),
          context: ({ req }) => {
            const headers = req.headers;
            return { headers };
          },
        });
    
    
        await apolloServer.start();
    
        apolloServer.applyMiddleware({ app });
    
        app.listen(4000, () => {
          console.log('Server started on http://localhost:4000/graphql');
        });
      }
    
    
    }
```

but it says :
Type

> 'import("node_modules/@types/express/index").Application'
> is not assignable to type
> 'import("node_modules/apollo-server-express/node_modules/@types/express/index").Application'.
> Types of property 'get' are incompatible.
> ApolloServer.d.ts(15, 5): The expected type comes from property 'app' which is declared here on type 'ServerRegistration'

didnt  had  any error   in a previous project that uses same dependencies  without even  casting it to Application
but  when i tried  npm update on it i have   the issue  in both projects

package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@typegoose/typegoose": "^12.0.0",
    "apollo-server-express": "^3.13.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-jwt-authz": "^2.4.1",
    "express-oauth2-jwt-bearer": "^1.6.0",
    "graphql": "^15.8.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "jwks-rsa": "^3.1.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^4.0.0",
    "mongoose": "^8.0.4",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.8",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.2.1",
    "type-graphql": "^1.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.5",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.14",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed by casting it  to "any"

```
const app = express() as any;
```